# How to get an attribute 's value in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, attr

I'm beginner with angular, and I don't know how to get an attribute 's value.
As exemple, I have a button with a value attribute, and I'would like to get that value to play with, when I call a function, in this case the function `changeArea`, here is the code.

In this case I want to get the value of the value attribute which is 0. But I have no idea on the way I can access it.

```
<button class="btn btn-{{ (gesture.area_id == '0') && 'primary' || 'default' }}" 
    type="button" 
    value="0" 
    ng-click="changeArea(gesture.area_id,gesture.id)">
</button>
```

EDIT:

Let'say I have several buttons and I need them to have a unique value. Can I do something like that to the others value attribute: {{myButtonValue+1}} and then for the other {{myButtonValue+2}} and so on ? Sorry, I can't test it at the moment, that's why I ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `ng-click` you can pass the click event `$event` to your function.

```
<button class="btn btn-{{ (gesture.area_id == '0') && 'primary' || 'default' }}" 
    type="button" 
    value="0" 
    ng-click="changeArea(gesture.area_id,gesture.id,$event)">
</button>
```

Then in your `$scope.changeArea` you can do this:

```
$scope.changeArea = function (param1, param2, e)
```

From there you should be able to grab the elements values.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#-event-

Answer (score 0):

Set it to a `$scope` variable and use that:

```
<button value="{{myButtonValue}}"
```

And then you can do:

```
$scope.myButtonValue = 3; //or whatever
```

Comment: Let'say I have several buttons and I need them to have a unique value. Can I do something like that to the others value attribute: {{myButtonValue+1}} and then for the other {{myButtonValue+2}} and so on ? Sorry, I can't test it at the moment, that's why I ask.